# Foundation 5 full width page with no padding or margin in columns

Tags: html, css

I am using foundation5 I want to build a full width page having no padding between columns Is there any way I can do it

Answer (score 2):

To remove the default padding between columns, all you need to do is add the 'collapse' class to the row div:

```
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="medium-6 columns">stuff</div>
      <div class="medium-6 columns">here</div>
    </div>
```

You can also customize the gap between columns in your settings file

To make the grid stretch to the full page width, just find the variable $row-width: in your settings file, uncomment it and change it to 100% (default is 1200px I think)

Comment: As always, I upvoted this as it was downvoted without comments. Cheers Dave, try to find out why it was downvoted and fix it if necessary.